# How to connect to a SQL Server localhost with jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have an installed SQL Server. Now I want to connect to it with jdbc.
Problem is, I don´t know what to put in the user. When I login, I don´t put in any user name.
`"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=;database=autoskola;"`

Answer (score 0):

Open Sql Server Management Studio, right click **Logins**  in **Security** folder on the left then select **New Login**. Type a username and select SQL Server Authentication and type your password. And if you want, you can define roles for this user in **Server Roles** section on the left.

But if you still want to do it without db username and password, you can use Windows Authentication. Check [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server).

Comment: Is there a way to connect without creating a new Login? Just curious.

Comment: You can create a Truted connection by adding "integratedSecurity=true" to your connection string. It will be like: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=autoskola;integratedSecurity=true" Check my edited answer.

Comment: Now it writes this error:May 07, 2017 11:24:36 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Comment: No, Its like this conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)

Comment: ok keep it like that, download the missing dll file from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774 and copy the dll file to the System32 folder.

Comment: Where exactly is this folder?

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32